# displaying menu items

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a web application that use Dynamic Drive's javascript + css to create a menu in my Joomla application.
it looks like this

Home-About Me-Contact Me

In About Me, there are sub items {My pictures, My Blog, My Everything}
Inside My Everything, there are other subitems {My favorite music, My cooked food}

In Joomla 2.5 administrative system, I created them and set them as children already, And when my mouse is over AboutMe, the sub menu level 1 is displayed but when my mouse is over My Everything, there is nothing displayed at all.
This is the query string
Code:

> $query  = "SELECT * FROM #__menu WHERE parent_id = ".$parent." and
>   language='".$language."' and published = 1" ;

but it gets only the subitems of About Me.

Do you know how to get all the Mypicture's subitems ? Thank you...

Comment: Check the database: Do the items you expect to see have "published = 1"? Also do those items have the same parent_id as the actual item? Do these records also have the same language setting as the one you have in your app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the query again, to find the menus with the parent_id for the "My Everything". The "My Everything" submenus do not have the same parent as the others

Comment: Although I don't know how your menu works, usually on dynamic menus you will either do what christopher above wrote, every time you hover on top of one menu or get all the menus and their submenus upon page load and pass them in the menu control so that they are displayed all the time without having to run the query again.